# How to make programs like nano/pico in linux

Tags: linux, console, editor, console-application

I was wondering how to make a program that can output to every line of the console and not just output a line to be tacked on to the bottom.  How can I get control of the whole console like that so I could write console based apps?

Comment: [Relevant](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5800/what-protocol-standard-is-used-by-terminals/5802#5802)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) or similar library to make that kind of UI - check out [GNU ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) for example.

[Wikipedia summarises ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) nicely

> ncurses is a programming library
>   providing an API, allowing the
>   programmer to write text user
>   interfaces in a terminal-independent
>   manner. It's a toolkit for developing
>   "GUI-like" apps which run under a
>   terminal emulator. It also optimizes
>   screen changes, in order to reduce the
>   latency experienced when using remote
>   shells.

To get started, check out the [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)